# Azure Canary Deployment - Use variable for increments

Tags: azure, variables, deployment, azure-pipelines

We are using a canary deployment job in Azure.  The job is defined in a template.  We want to set the "increments:" parameter at runtime to a single value (i.e. [ 50 ] rather than [ 25, 50 ]).  The value is an output of a prior job.  I've tried a few different approaches and receive various errors immediately in the screen where one tries to start the pipeline, before it actually starts.

Simplified yaml:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: preValidationCanary
    steps:
      - task: PythonScript@0
        name: setCanaryDeploymentVariables
        script: |
          # Do stuff to determine percentage
          print("##vso[task.setvariable variable=%s;isOutput=true]%s" % ("deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage_global", trafficPercentageInt ))

  - deployment: deployCanary
    dependsOn:
      - preValidationCanary
    variables:
      deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage: $[ dependencies.preValidationCanary.outputs['setCanaryDeploymentVariables.deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage_global'] ]
    strategy:
      canary:
        increments: $[deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage]
```

I've tried passing just the number from the prior job, and then using this syntax:

```yaml
increments: [ $[deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage] ]
```

This results in the error: "While parsing a flow sequence, did not find expected ',' or ']'."

I've tried using the macro syntax:

```yaml
increments: [ $(deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage) ]
```

This results in the error: "Mapping values are not allowed in this context."

In case there was an issue expanding a number into the brackets, I tried passing a string from the prior job, using the runtime syntax:

```yaml
- task: PythonScript@0
  name: setCanaryDeploymentVariables
  script: |
    # Do stuff to determine percentage
    print("##vso[task.setvariable variable=%s;isOutput=true]%s" % ("deploy_canaryTrafficSplitPercentage_global", str(trafficPercentageInt) ))
```

This also provided the error: "While parsing a flow sequence, did not find expected ',' or ']'."

So I tried this with macro syntax, which provided the error: "Mapping values are not allowed in this context."

I'll continue to beat my head against this, but if anyone either knows how this can be done, or knows that it cannot be done, please reply.

Comment: Just a small update.  I've tried several forms of non-output variables.  I defined the variable in a variables: block at the global level from the file that I call this template, as well as nested into the Stage from the file that I call this template.  Used both macro and runtime dereference methods.  No luck so far.

Comment: The closest that I have gotten is to get a better error message.  When I specify a variable in the yaml that calls this template at the stage level (stage scoped variable).  Then modify that variable in my pre-step in the template using a non-output task.setvariable.  Then reference the variable like this: ```increments: [ $(canaryTrafficSplitPercentage) ]```.  I receive the error: "Failed to parse canary strategy increments. Ensure increments input is an array of integers. For e.g.: [ 10, 20 ]"

Comment: I think I've solved a similar problem by using the verbose multi-line form of YAML arrays, i.e. instead of `[ $(...) ]` writing `- $(...)` on an indented new line under `increments:`.  I've not used the deployments feature though, so I'm not certain it's the same issue.